# Django migration file in an other app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's imagine a following simplified Django project:

```
<root>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/externalapp/shop
<root>/myapp
```

`myapp` also extends `externalapp.shop.models` models by adding a few fields. `manage.py makemigrations` did generated following schema migration file called *0004_auto_20150410_2001.py*:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    # __init__ is added by me as an attempt how to tell django's
    # migration loader operations are for the different application
    def __init__(self, name, app_label):
        super(Migration, self).__init__(name, 'shop')

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '__first__'),
        ('shop', '0003_auto_20150408_0958'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='vat',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to='myapp.VAT', null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

If the above migration schema is placed in `<root>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/externalapp/shop/migrations/` path by default, `manage.py migrate` succeeds and table fields are correctly added.

However if I do move the above migration file into `myapp/migrations/`, following `manage.py migrate` fails with

*django.core.management.base.CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected (0001_initial, 0004_auto_20150410_2001 in myapp).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'*

error message I can't quite understand and suggested `makemigrations --merge` fails with expected:

*ValueError: Could not find common ancestor of set([u'0001_initial', u'0004_auto_20150410_2001'])*

I've tried to override `migrations.Migration.__init__` to alter derived `app_label` but seems migration loader ignores it.

How adjust migration file so it can work from other application ?
The reason is in production `externalapp` sources can't be directly touched, are read only.

Comment: How do you add fields to the external app from your own app? That sounds like a potential disaster. As for the migrations, all migrations within a single app must form a single, unbranched path from the first to the last migration. You have two endpoints for your migrations. You should change the `('myapp', '__first__')` dependency to depend on the last migration in `myapp`.

Comment: @knbk Thanks for the hint. It fixes conflicting migrations error, but new with *state.models[app_label, self.model_name_lower].fields.append((self.name, field))
KeyError: (u'myapp', u'product')* arises. How explicitly tell django/south it should operate on `externalapp.shop` instead of `myapp` for this specific migration ? *adding a few fields from other application, if you know what you are doing, need not to be a disaster, even a simpler and faster solution (no extra table & sql joins).  [Related blog](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/) about.*

Comment: Update: I did dropped the database, uncommented Migration initializer and rerun all migrations and it started to work ! Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To move a migration file around a Django project, like in case of injecting models of other applications, you need to ensure in your `django.db.migrations.Migration` descendant:

- explicitly set application name, as migrations loader derives it automatically by app where migration file resides and would attempt to perform operations on different models otherwise
- notify migrations recorder it provides migration for other application or it would still consider migration as unapplied (records about applied migrations are stored in a table, currently named `django_migrations`)

I've solved the issue in migration initializer which may look like:

```
from django.db import migrations

TARGET_APP = 'shop'    # application label migration is for

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def __init__(self, name, app_label):
        # overriding application operated upon
        super(Migration, self).__init__(name, TARGET_APP)

    # specify what original migration file it replaces
    # or leave migration loader confused about unapplied migration
    replaces = ((TARGET_APP, __module__.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]),)
```

It does work for me and find it enough generic way.

Eager to hear about a better/simpler solution if possible.

Comment: Can you please explain this line: replaces = ((TARGET_APP, __module__..rsplit('.', 1)[-1]),)

Comment: @Mikael `replaces` is a class variable which specifies tuple pairs in format `(<original migration>, <new migration>)`, ie. which migration substitutes the original one. `__module__` specifies (dot separated) module path where the migration class descendant is being defined. `rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` extracts the tail of the path.

Comment: Ah, the confusing part was  __module__ , now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since Django 1.9 there’s the `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting that you can use to pull the migrations of "foreign" models into your app.

As outlined in the [FeinCMS docs](http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrations.html), you create a new package (folder with `__init__.py`) in your app and list the foreign apps in settings like so:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'one': 'yourapp.foreigners.one',
    'other': 'yourapp.foreigners.other',
}
```

Afterwards you can just `manage.py makemigrations one other` etc.