# Using django migrations, how do I alter auth_permission field length?

Tags: django

I have just upgraded to Django 1.7 and I have some issues with some of my migrations. Before upgrading I used South to handle data migrations and one migration I had was to alter the field length for the name field in auth_permissions.

How can I write the same migration using django migrations >= 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that change still required?  The length of that field was a known issue for a long time, but the most recent update in the bug tracker says it was [quintupled in length](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8162).

If you still want it to be even longer, you probably want [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

**EDIT**: Giving up on this for now.  Writing a migration that is stored in app A but applied to app B involves deeper monkeying than I have time for.

Suggested routes:

1. Use [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) in a migration within one of your own apps to tweak the field by hand.
2. Fork Django 1.7.8, add the auth migration described in the comments, pip install against that github repo.
3. Use Django 1.8, where [this change is standard](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.1/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0002_alter_permission_name_max_length.py).

Comment: Not sure this was included in the 1.7.8 release. Anyway, I can't figure out how to modify the auth_permissions model using data migrations.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d538e37e1b14603d1d0c94f185f378fc0ed1e53f/tests/migrations/migrations_test_apps/alter_fk/author_app/migrations/0002_alter_id.py) with a max_length change?

Comment: Since the auth_permission is in a different app I can't use that. It can't manage to find the proper model.

Comment: In a toy project as proof of concept, I was able to make it work with `python manage.py makemigrations --empty auth
` to make a file and [these](https://gist.github.com/bwarren2/8b20f3be7f281f0d388f) contents.  I am still poking at writing the migration somewhere more maintainable, but it involves [overriding some inside logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575802/django-migration-file-in-an-other-app).

Comment: Ah this is most likely what I need to do. Will check in the morning. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

having problem with permission name length
using Django 1.8 
Python 3.4.4 
(these are the latest versions that MySQL 5.6+ works with)
changed the base\schema.py

in _alter_field(...)

```
# ********* altered - start
fragment, other_actions = self._alter_column_type_sql(table=model._meta.db_table, old_field=old_field, new_field=new_field.column, new_type=new_type)
# ******** end
```

changed the definition to:

```
def _alter_column_type_sql(self, table, old_column, column, type):
```

That's it. All the migration works