# How to store third party apps migrations in django

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-scheduler

I'm fairly new to python and django, and trying to build a simple calendar based on django-scheduler package.
According to django-scheduler docs, a custom base class can be used to add additional fields, managers and such.

So, I used an abstract model to add a new field:

```
#myproject/customer_calendar/models.py
from django.db import models
from main.models import Customer

class CalendarAbstract(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(to=Customer, null=True, blank=True, related_name='calendar')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And added this to settings.py

```
SCHEDULER_BASE_CLASSES = {
    'Calendar': ['customer_calendar.models.CalendarAbstract'],
}
```

Now, if I use makemigrations command, a new migration is created inside scheduler app (which is located in site-packages of the current virtual env), which doesn't allow me to keep track of migrations via VCS.

I've found a couple of solutions:

1) Keep the whole scheduler app inside my project. According to SO it' s considered a bad practice and third-party apps should always be retrieved via pip.

2) Use django setting to store all django-scheduler migrations inside my calendar app

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'schedule': 'customer_calendar.migrations',
}
```

The second one looks good to me, but I don't know if it's considered to be a valid solution to this problem.
Is there any other ways to store third-party apps migrations?

Answer (score 1):

> The second one looks good to me, but I don't know if it's considered
>   to be a valid solution to this problem. Is there any other ways to
>   store third-party apps migrations?

As also stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891483/2996101), [FeinCMS docs](https://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrations.html) recommend the use of [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#migration-modules) to monitor the migrations of FeinCMS as a third-party app.

> FeinCMS itself does not come with any migrations. It is recommended
>   that you add migrations for FeinCMS models yourself inside your
>   project.
>
> ...
>
> - Create a new folder named migrate in your app with an empty **init**.py inside.
> - Add the following configuration to your settings.py:
>
> ```
>     MIGRATION_MODULES = {
>          'page': 'yourapp.migrate.page',
>          'medialibrary': 'yourapp.migrate.medialibrary', }
> ```
>
> You must not use `migrations` as folder name for the FeinCMS migrations,
>   otherwise Django will get confused.