# Django makemigrations in production?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm new to Django but one concern I'm running into is whether running `makemigrations` as part of the production deployment process is safe/deterministic?

The main reason is some 3rd party apps will create new migrations beyond the pre-defined ones, i.e. [hordak](https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-hordak/blob/master/hordak/models/core.py#L138) for example, when a new currency is added via `CURRENCIES` in `settings.py`.

Since a currency can be added anytime later and these are part of an 3rd party app the migrations are not checked in to the repo.

This requires `makemigrations` to be run on deploy? This seems dangerous since there will be untraceable changes to the DB?

- Is a way to explicitly check-in to the repo 3rd party migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question: [How to store third party apps migrations in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153776/how-to-store-third-party-apps-migrations-in-django?rq=1)

Using `MIGRATION_MODULES` in `settings.py` you can relocate 3rd party migration files removing the need to perform `makemigrations` in production.